# В vaadin как добавить pdf файл

Tags: java, vaadin

Как добавить pdf файл в vaadin ?

То есть, написал программу и теперь мне его "Руководство Пользователя" - добавить в систему, типа: Help.

Comment: Что значит добавить: показать его на странице, дать ссылку на скачивание или что-то другое? Где храниться файл: на внешнем ресурсе, в БД, в приложении, в файловой системе? Распишите подробно ожидаемый результат.

Comment: @defaultlocale для просмотра, чтобы пользователи смогли прочесть и дальше работали по "Руководство". Можно хранить в файловой системе.

Answer (score 2):

Непосредственно в самом Vaadin **нет**  компонента для просмотра PDF на странице.

Однако, на сайте Vaadin есть репозиторий компонентов для Vaadin от сторонних разработчиков и по запросу *PDF* Вы легко можете найти подходящий компонент
https://vaadin.com/directory/search?sort=rating&keyword=pdf

Например PdfViewer

https://vaadin.com/directory/component/pdfviewer

В использовании прост:

```
 PdfViewer c = new PdfViewer(file);
 layout.addComponent(c);
```

Ну а если честно, то работая с Vaadin, Вы должны уметь разрабатывать собственные компоненты, потому что далеко не всегда Вы сможете находить то что нужно именно Вам.

А для этого Вам будут необходимы так или иначе достаточные знания HTML/CSS/JavaScript и умение все это внедрять в Ваше приложение на Vaadin.

Вы можете использовать какую-то готовую JavaScript библиотеку и `CustomLayout`

https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/layout/layout-customlayout.html

В качестве JavaScript используете например PDF.js от Mozilla или WebViewer от PdfTron

- https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/
- https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/index.html

Создаёте файл:
/VAADIN/themes/***themename***/layouts/***mylayout***.html

Где

- ***themename*** - имя используемой темы (по умолчанию - Valo)
- ***mylayout*** - имя layout'а (потом Вы должны будете указать его при создании CustomLayout)

Потом создаёте CustomLayout

```
CustomLayout content = new CustomLayout("layoutname");
```

Указать путь к дополнительным скриптам или стилям вы Можете с помощью аннотации в UI - классе

```
@StyleSheet("app://../VAADIN/themes/valo/additional.css")
@JavaScript("app://../VAADIN/themes/valo/additional.js")
public class VaadinUI extends UI {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: спасибо за направления.